# Lifting a quadratic system to a non-vanishing vector field on $S^{3}$ or $T^{1} S^{2}$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, fibre-bundles, foliations, limit-cycles

Let $P:S^{3}\to S^{2}$ be  the  Hopf fibration. For a vector  field $X$ on $S^{2}$ there is  a  **non-vanishing** vector  field  $\tilde{X}$ on $S^{3}$ such that $DP(\tilde{X})=X$. It is  constructed in two  steps:

1) (I thank D. Panazzolo for  this  first step) We  choose a   2-dimensional  subbundle  $E$ of $TS^{3}$ which is  transverse to one-dimensional $\ker DP$. Then  $DP:E_{x}\to T_{P(x)}S^{2} $ is  a  linear isomorphism. Then $DP^{-1}(X)$ is  a  tangent  vector  field on $S^{3}$ which  vanishes on $P^{-1}(\text{singularities of X})$

2) We choose  a  non-vanishing  vector  field $Z$ on $S^{3}$ tangent to the  Hopf fibration. Then $\tilde{X}=DP^{-1}(X)+Z$ is the desired vector field. In fact $\tilde{X}$    gives us  a one-dimensional  foliation of $S^{3}$ whose  leaves  are  mapped by $P$ to the  solutions  of  $X$ on $S^{2}$.

[Edit: I just realize that a combination of
the above 2 steps is mentioned in [Ghys' 1994 Bourbaki seminar](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/constructionchamps.pdf), see the first paragraph of page 285.

On the  other hand,  we  know  that the  singularities are  the  main  obstructions in the  study of  limit  cycles. (For instance, see the "Non-accumulation theorem" by Ilyashenko or the subject of "finite cyclicity of polycycles" by Roussarie, Dumortier, Rousseau et al.).
  So the  above  construction  is  a  motivation to  ask the  following  questions:

> 1.Let  $Y$  be  a  non-vanishing  analytic  vector field on $S^{3}$. Is it true to say that $Y$ has  only  a  finite  number of invariant attractor  torus? (Motivated by ["Finiteness theorem for  limit cycles"](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.2/Main/icm1990.2.1259.1270.ocr.pdf) by Ilyashenko.)
>
> 2. From the  view of  limit  cycle theory, is it useful to study the (various)    lifting  of  quadratic  systems on $S^{2}$ to   non-vanishing  vector fields on $S^{3}$?  By  quadratic  system I  mean  the  [Poincaré  compactification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178077/why-poincare-sphere-compactification-and-not-torus-compactification) of  a  degree $2$ planar polynomial  vector  field  $$ \begin{cases} \dot x=ax+by+cx^{2}+dxy+ey^{2}\\\dot y=a'x+b'y+c'x^{2}+d'xy+e'y^{2}. \end{cases}$$
>
> 3.Can we lift an  algebraic vector  field  to  a   non-vanishing  algebraic  vector  field? An algebraic   vector  field on  $S^{3}$ is   the Poincaré  compactification of  a  polynomial  vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Finally, it is  natural  to  ask: Is the  Hopf  fibration the  only $S^{1}$  fibre  bundle from $S^{3}$ to $S^{2}$ (up to  equivalency of  fibre  bundle)?

> **Note 1:** It would be interesting to look at the behavior of $\mathrm{Div}(\tilde{X})$, since this divergence must vanish somewhere between two invariant torus which  covers two limit cycles $\gamma_{1}$ inside $\gamma_{2}$. This  is  a motivation to ask: Can we obtain a lifting $\tilde{X}$ whose divergence is constant on each fibre? Even if the  answer is negative,  we still have a vanishing result  for  some  quantity associated to  a vector field on $S^{2}$. The latter statement would be more clear after looking at some thing similar to [Dulac-Bendixson criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem).
>
> **Note 2:** One  can repeat the same initial question of non-vanishing  lifting vector field for $\pi:TS^{2}\to S^{2}$ where $\pi$ is the natural projecting map (or lifting the vector fields on $S^{2}$  via circle bundle $P:T^{1} S^{2}\to S^{2}$, where $T^{1}S^{2}$ is the unit tangent bundle).  For this type of lifting, we possibly  need  the answer of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186401/a-question-on-tangent-bundle-and-second-tangent-bundle?lq=1).

Comment: Answer to the last question : the isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundles on a space $X$ form a group, identified with 
 $[X,B\mathbb{S}^1]$. When $X=\mathbb{S}^2$ this group is  $\pi _2(B\mathbb{S}^1)\cong \pi _1(\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. The Hopf fibration is a generator, but you have also all its multiples.

Comment: @abx thanks for your answer to the last question. The total space correspond to generator is $S^{3}$  with Hopf  map. What is  the  total space of multiple generator by 2? and  what is the projecting map?

Comment: @Ali:  If you just divide $S^3$ by the action of the $n$-element cyclic subgroup of $S^1$ (when $n\ge 1$), you'll get the bundle $\Sigma_n\to S^2$, and these are all of the examples.

Comment: @RobertBryant Prof. Bryant Thank you  for  your  comment. So We conclude that the  Hopf  fibration is  the only $S^{1}$-fibre bundle from $S^{3}$ to $S^{2}$?I have another question in this  fibration, are there two disjoint  fibres  which are "linked" to each other?Is there  a  fibre which is  knoted?  And  what is  an elementary refrence  for classification of $S^{1}$  fibre  bundles, in particular the space $\Sigma_{n}$ which you mentioned?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  No.  $S^3\to S^2$ is the only *simply-connected* $S^1$-fiber bundle over $S^2$:  Each of the $\Sigma_n$ is also an $S^1$-fiber bundle over $S^2$.  Also, you have to distinguish the two $S^1$-fiber bundles you get by reversing the $S^1$-action on any given $S^1$-fiber bundle (this makes sense because $S^1$ is abelian).  Thus, there is actually a $\mathbb{Z}$-family of $S^1$-fiber bundles, with $\Sigma_n$ and $\Sigma_{-n}$ being topologically the same space but not equivalent bundles (when $n\not=0$).  Check Milnor and Stasheff for example, for proofs.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  In $S^3$, two different fibers are linked, but, of course, they are not knotted.  In $\Sigma_n$ with $n>1$, I'm not sure what you might mean by `knotted'.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Finally, the $S^1$-bundles over $M$ correspond one-to-one, to elements in $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.  I think that there is a proof in Milnor-Stasheff, but another place might be Atiyah's *Lectures on $K$-theory*.  Check in those places for proofs.