# A (different) foliation arising from Hopf fibration

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations, hopf-fibration

In this  question, first  we  fix an isomorphism between $TS^{3}$ and $S^{3}\times \mathbb{R}^{3}$.(To be more  precise we consider the global trivialization of $TS^{3}$ with help of $3$ global sections $\{ix,jx,kx\}$, $x\in S^{3}$, with  quaternioun multiplications). So  every  map $S^{3}\to S^{2}\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is  counted as a unique (unit speed) vector field on $S^{3}$. In  particular the  Hopf  map

$$p:S^{3}\to S^{2}\; \text{with} \;p(z,w)= (\parallel  z\parallel^{2}-\parallel  w\parallel^{2},\;2z\bar{w})$$.

defines  a  unique  vector  field on $S^{3}$, a  non singular  foliation of $S^{3}$. We denote this  vector  field on $S^{3}$ by $\tilde{X}$.

> What  is  known about the  dynamics of this  vector  field(Foliation)? Existence of  periodic orbit? Invariant  torus? (A possible  full dynamical   description?)   According to the [following notation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3) what  type of  vector  field $X$ on $S^{2}$ can  be  lifted to $\tilde{X}$? Is  there  a  reference  which investigated this  particular  foliation of $S^{3}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the definition of the map $p$... You use complex coordinates on $S^{3} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$, but what coordinates do you use on $S^{2}$? Can you write the definition of $p$ in terms of the frame $\{ix, jx, kx\}$, please?

Comment: @OldřichSpáčil  I  got  that  formula of  hopf  fibration from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration. The  coordinate of $S^{2}$ is the  usual one:$S^{2}=\{(x,z)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{C}\mid |x|^{2}+\parallel z\parallel^{2}=1\}$. But the  hopf  map  is  a  map  defined on $S^{3}$  so how  you expect to  define it in term of fram which are  elements of $TS^{3}$ not $S^{3}$? Please let me know if I  should more clarify the  question.

Comment: This is what I meant: as you pointed out, the moving frame $\{ix, jx, kx\}$ trivializes the tangent bundle $TS^{3}$. But it also trivializes the **unit** tangent bundle because the frame is orthonormal, hence $STS^{3} \cong S^{3}\times S^{2}$. So, as you said,  any **unit** vector field on $S^{3}$ is identified using the moving frame with a smooth map $S^{3} \to S^{2}$. The map $p$ then describes the coordinates in the frame $\{ix, jx, kx\}$ of the corresponding unit vector field and I thought it would help to write down the vector field as a linear combination of $ix, jx, kx$.

Comment: Is not there still freedom left in choosing identifications between $S^2$ and the set of unit vectors in each tangent space? For example, does anything obstruct you in choosing them in such a way that the field will be just the field of unit tangents to the fibers of the Hopf map?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  very interesting point. I am thinking  about it...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  .. and are you concluding that the  answer to my main question is  independent of  a trivialization of $TS^{3}$, up to topological equivalent? So all thing is the  hopf fibration, up to topological equivalent? So we do not get some new  foliation of $S^{3}$?

Comment: On the contrary, I think the answer depends on the trivialization. For example I believe you also can choose trivialization in such way that the field becomes a constant field (of unit vectors parallel in the sense of some embedding of $S^3$ into $R^6$).