# A question on tangent bundle (and second tangent bundle)

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be  a $n$  dimensional manifold and $p:TM\to M$ be the projection map. Then $\ker Dp$ is  a  $n$ dimensional vector bundle on $TM$, as a sub bundle of $TT(M)$.

> For what type of  manifolds, $\ker Dp$ is  a trivial bundle? Or at least it admits  a  global non vanishing section? In particular put $M= S^{n}$. Does $\ker Dp$ admit  a nonvanishing global section?

I need to the  answer to this  question for the "Note" in the final part of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3)

Comment: The kernel of $Dp$ is canonically identified with the kernel of the bundle map $T^2 M \to TM$, thinking of $T^2M$ as the tangent bundle of $TM$.  The identification is via the involution of the double tangent bundle.  So your question is the same question as asking if the manifold $TM$ is parallelizable, which is the same question of if $TM \oplus TM \to M$ is a trivial vector bundle. I'm not sure if there's any cute answers to that question, but likely there's some cute sufficient conditions.

Comment: @RyanBudney  thanks for the comment. It remind me of  your  comment  to  one of my question about equivalency of two different structure of vector bundle on $T^{2}M\to TM$. you attached a pdf file of your lecture for a proof of this  some thing related to this. your comment is not available now. may you resend that file ?

Comment: @RyanBudney So should  I understand from your comment that every vector field on $S^{2}$ can be lifted to  a non vanishing vec. field on the unit  tangent bundle of $S^{2}$? By lifting I mean a  vector field on total space whose solution are mapped to the solution of our initial vec. field on $S^{2}$.

Comment: My differential geometry notes (couched in this iterated tangent bundle language and automorphisms of iterated tangent bundles) are here: http://rybu.org/DGNotes This material is in the 1st chapter, but the 3rd also covers some relevant material.

Comment: Could you re-state your last comment, perhaps using things like the maps $p$, $Dp$, and the bundle projection $\pi : T^2 M \to TM$ ?  I'm not quite sure which objects you're referring to.

Comment: @RyanBudney  I mean: let $P:T^{1}S^{2}\to S^{2}$ is the  natural projection from the unit tangent bundle. Is it possible to lift  a  vec. field on $S^{2}$ to  a  **nonvanishing** vec. field on $T^{1}S^{2}$? The  Motivation: As  I said [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3), I would like to run away from $S^{2}$ in any possible way.

Comment: Okay, yes, the answer to that question is yes.  This is because $TS^2 \oplus TS^2$ as a bundle over $S^2$ has an everywhere non-zero vector field (just take two vector fields on $S^2$ that have no common zeros).  You could then translate this vector field fibrewise to be sitting over any vector field of $TS^2 \to S^2$.

Comment: @RyanBudney   thanks a lot for your  help.