# Irrational closed orbits of vector fields on $S^2$ (Limit cycles and trace formula)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

> **Motivations:** We first introduce our motivations: We wish to find an operator-theoretical interpretation for the number of limit cycles of a  polynomial vector field on the plane. We quote the statement at page 9 of [this paper which is the main motivation for our post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332979/irrational-closed-orbits-of-vector-fields-on-s2-limit-cycles-and-trace-formu)

*The formulas we want to consider in this section relate the compact orbits of a flow with the alternating sum of suitable traces on cohomology*

Via Poincaré compactification, every planar polynomial vector  field  gives  us a  vector field $X$ on $S^2$ which has a lifting to a  non vanishing $S^1$-invariant vector field $\tilde{X}$ on the total space $S^3$ of the Hopf  fiber bundle  $S^3\to S^2$ [(see this question)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3-or-t1). The orthogonal complement of this vector field determines a $2$-dimensional distribution on $S^3$.

The Poincaré compactification is described at page 64 of the [following paper](https://scielo.conicyt.cl/pdf/proy/v22n3/art01.pdf) [VG]. For a brief description of this method see the  first paragraph of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178077/why-poincare-sphere-compactification-and-not-torus-compactification?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The  purpose of this post is to  apply the materials  of the paper ["Number theory  and  dynamical  system in foliated spaces"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204110.pdf) to  find  a possible **TRACE** interpretation for the upper bound for the number of  limit cycles  of  a planar  polynomial vector field. In particular we wish to apply the  materials of the  first paragraph of page  11 of the above  linked paper. So we lift  a  vector  field  $X$ on $S^2$ to a non-vanishing vector  field $\tilde{X}$  on $S^3$, then we consider the   $2$-dimensional  distribution on $S^3$ which is  perpendicular to $\tilde{X}$ and  we  wish to know if this  distribution is  an integrable distribution which is  invariant under flow of  $\tilde{X}$. [But assuming that all things go well, which is  not really the case,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332989/a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3-whose-flow-does-not-preserve-any-transvers?noredirect=1&lq=1) we have  a  problem as follows: "A relation between closed orbits of  $X$ and  closed orbits of $\tilde{X}$". It is possible that we lose our closed orbit of  the  base space after lifting to the total space. This  is  main motivation of this post. Now we describe our main question:

**Main Question:**
We  fix the standard Riemannian metric of  $S^3$ and we  consider the Hopf fibration $P:S^3 \to S^2$. Let $Z$ be the unit length   tangent vector  field  to fibers of this fiber bundle. Assume that $H\subset TS^3$ be the horizontal space of this fiber bundle  which is  perpendicular  $Z$. So for every $x\in S^3$, the  linear map $DP(x)$  is  a linear isomorphism between $H_x$ and  $T_{P(x) S^2}$.

For  a  vector  field $X$ on $S^2$ we consider  the vector field $\tilde{X}=Z+DP^{-1}(X)$ on $S^3$. So $DP(\tilde{X})=X$ and $\tilde{X}$ is  a non-vanishing  invariant vector field on the total space $S^3$.

> Is there an example of  a  vector field on $S^2$ which possesses a  closed orbit $\gamma$, but the $\tilde{X}$-invariant torus $P^{-1}(\gamma)$ does not contain any closed orbit? (That is, the restriction of $\tilde{X}$ to $P^{-1}(\gamma)$ would define a  Kronecker foliation, an  irrational foliation of torus. (Any  such closed orbit $\gamma$ is called  an irrational closed orbit.
>
> Is there an example of this situation with the extra assumption that $X$ is the Poincaré  compactification of a polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

[VG] Vidal, Claudio; Gómez, Pedro An extension of the Poincaré compactification and a geometric interpretation. Proyecciones 22 (2003), no. 3, 161–180.

Comment: Have you already tried a vector field on $S^2$ with only two zeros and only one closed orbit, say, the equator? Because $\tilde X$ does not depend linearly on $X$, changing the length of $X$ should produce an example.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  Very  interesting point. You  mean that instead of  $Z+\tilde{X}$  we  consider $Z+f\tilde{X}$. Yes?  To  be  honest  I  did  not  think to this  situation of    equator(Infinity). The reason  is that it contains  a  singularity  when we poincare  compactify  a planar  algebraic vector  field to  a  vector  field  on sphere.In this  case every possible  $Z+f\tilde{X}$ is  not  a Kronecker foliation. But  your idea can apply to every  regular closed  orbit in the  base space. So according to your comment  i think that the  answer to this post is  Yes.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  So  it would  be interesting  to  consider  the following version of  conjectures  and  theorems  in the  linked paper: "For  a 2  dimensional  foliation of  a  3  manifold  which is  invariant under the  flow  of  a vector  field $V$, can one introduce  a  trace  formula which  right hand  side  involves $V$- invariant torous( As well as non degenerate closed orbits).

Comment: @SebastianGoette  What about the following: We lift the  vector  field  $X$ to $\tilde{X}$ but  we  dont  add the  vertical term $Z$. In this case can the preimage  of  a  regular closed orbit be  a  Kronecker torus?

Comment: To your last comment: now this is a question of the holonomy of the connection on the Hopf- (or tautological) bundle. If the periodic orbit is moved a little, the holonomy changes, and so it is possible to produce Kronecker foliations upstairs.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  On the other extreme the Novikov theorem mentioned in page 285( 2 paragraph before section 3) of the following paper is a  motivation to be hopfull that we do not lose our closed orbit after we  lift to $S^3$.

Comment: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/constructionchamps.pdf