# Trace class operators in the unit ball of a finite dimensional subvector space of $B(H)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $F\subset B(H)$ be  a  finite dimensional  subvector  space of the  space of  all bounded operators on a  Hilbert space.

**Question:** Is there an upper bound for $$\{|tr(T)| \text{where} \quad T\in F\quad  \text{is a trace class operator of unit norm}\}$$

An indirect but relevant motivation for this question is  mentioned in the "Motivation" part of this post:

[Irrational closed orbits of vector fields on $S^2$(Limit cycles and trace formula)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332979/irrational-closed-orbits-of-vector-fields-on-s2limit-cycles-and-trace-formul)

**Remark:** I have already learned from a specialist that the answer is "negative" if in this question  we replace "trace class operators" with "Fredholm operators" and "trace" with "Fredholm index".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is yes, there is an upper bound. The set of trace class operators $TC(H)$ is itself a linear subspace of $B(H)$, so $F' = F \cap TC(H)$ is a finite dimensional linear subspace of $TC(H)$, and we are interested in $\sup\{|{\rm tr}(T)|: T \in F', \|T\| = 1\}$. Since $F'$ is finite dimensional, the restrictions of the trace norm and the operator norm to $F'$ are equivalent. This means that there is a constant $C$ such that $|{\rm tr}(T)| \leq C\cdot \|T\|$ for all $T \in F'$.