# Hilbert 16th problem and dynamical Lefschetz trace formula

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, open-problems, foliations

I  would  like to apply the  known  version of the  conjectural formula  (11) page !0  of  the paper [Number theory and  dynamical Lefschetz trace formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204110.pdf).

**Disclaimer:** I  do  not  have a  complete understanding of  this  formula  but I  can  get an  sketch of it. I just know that both sides of the  formula are not number but  distribution. I also  know the meaning of ingredient of the  formula. I  wish to apply it to  find an  appropriate  application in limit cycle theory.

To  start this way,  I  have  three  precise questions:

**Question 1:** In the  right  hand  side of the formula (11), is  not  necessary to assume  that there are only a  finite number of non degenerate periodic  orbits $\gamma$(As they are appeared in the  sum $\sum$ of the right side of the formula)? Is it implicitly included in the  assumptions of that formula? I  think that even the  non degeneracy  assumption of periodic orbits does not  **easily** imply the  finite ness of such  periodic orbits. Is not  possible that a  sequence of  non degenerate periodic orbits  accumulate to a  non periodic  orbit which is  a  kind  of  complicated and strange attractor?

**Question 2:**(This  question is  completely different from the previous one but there are [some  motivations from this posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332989/a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3-whose-flow-does-not-preserve-any-transvers)  And  also this post [Lifting  a  Quadratic  System  to  a  non  Vanishing  vector 
 field  on $S^3$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3-or-t1?noredirect=1&lq=1))

A polynomial  vector  field  on the plane [gives us an analytic  vector  field $X$ on $S^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178077/why-poincare-sphere-compactification-and-not-torus-compactification?noredirect=1&lq=1). Put  $\tilde{X}$ for the  obvious  lifting of  $X$ on $S^2\times S^1$ with $\tilde{X}=X+\partial/\partial{\theta}$

> Is there a  quadratic  polynomial  vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with  Poincare  compactification $X$ such that $\tilde{X}$  on $S^2\times S^1$  does  not  admit  a 2  dimensional transversal foliation which is  invariant under the  flow of $\tilde{X}$.

**The reason we  consider Quadratic  system:**

Note that [every quadratic  system is  a  geodesible vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648) but  it is not the  case [for  higher degree polynomial vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273970/a-cubic-system-with-two-nested-limit-cycles-with-opposite-orientations?noredirect=1&lq=1). On the other hand, in dimension 2, if a  vector  field $X$ is  geodesible then there is  a  transversal field $Y$ with $[X,Y] \parallel Y$ this implies that orbits of  $Y$ are invariant under flow  of $X$. So this make us to be hopeful a  little  that the  product vector field  $\tilde{X}=X+\partial/\partial \theta$ admit a  transversal 2  dimensional foliation which is  invariant under the flow of  $\tilde{X}$. Existence of  such transversal foliation is the  key condition in the paper we linked in the  first lines of this post.

**The reason we consider $S^2\times S^1$ rather than $S^3$:**

The  lifting of the simplest vector  field $X=0$ to  the  Hopf  vector  field  on $S^3$ [does  not admit  a  transversal foliation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332989/a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3-whose-flow-does-not-preserve-any-transvers/333153#333153).

**Question 3:**  When we lift a  vector  field  $X$ to  a  non vanishing vector  field $\tilde{X}$ on $S^3, S^2\times S^1\quad\text{or}\quad T^1 S^2$,  it is  possible that the preimage  of  a  closed orbit, which is an invariant torus, would not contain any closed orbit, so  we loose our  closed orbits.[please see the  comment by Sebastian  Goette in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332979/irrational-closed-orbits-of-vector-fields-on-s2-limit-cycles-and-trace-formu). With terminologies in the linked paper, let  we have  a  3  manifold  foliated by  2 dimensional  leaves whch is  compatible  with  a  flow $X$. So is there an  analogy of  the  formula  (11) in page 10 of the  linked  paper in the  first lines of this post whose right side depends on invariant torus of $X$ as well as closed orbits of $X$?

**Remark:** The   concept ["Blue  Sky  catastrophe"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Blue-sky_catastrophe#Historical_note) and difficulties occured  in ["Finitness theorem for Limit  Cycles"](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-94) are motivations  for  the  first question of this post.