# A kind of heat equation on a foliated 3D manifold whose leaves are invariant under the flow of a vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, foliations, heat-equation

Assume that $\mathcal{F}$  is  a  foliation of  a  $3$ dimensional  compact  Riemannian manifold  $M$  which is  invariant under flow  of  a transversal non vanishing vector  field $X$. Let $\Delta_{\mathcal{F}}$ be  the  Laplace operator on each leaf which comes by restriction of  Riemannian metric of $M$ to leaves.

Let  $A=\{f\in C^{\infty}(M)\mid \Delta_{\mathcal{F}}f=X.f\}$

Is $A$ invariant under the  derivation $g\mapsto X.g$? Under which condition the later is the case? What is  an example of this  situation, invariance of $A$,  with extra  condition that the codimension  of the derivation operator $(g\mapsto X.g)|A$ is  a  finite number?

This  question is some how  motivated by the following two posts(An indirect  motivation not a direct motivation):

[Elliptic operators corresponds to non vanishing vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields)

[Hilbert 16th problem and dynamical Lefschetz trace formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333425/hilbert-16th-problem-and-dynamical-lefschetz-trace-formula)

Comment: The title recalls me " The Horrible and Terrifying Deeds and Words of the Very Renowned Pantagruel King of the Dipsodes, Son of the Great Giant Gargantua" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua_and_Pantagruel).

Comment: @user64494  what is the reason the title of this post recalls  you the title of that novel/