# A non-geodesible foliation of $S^3$ or $S^2\times S^1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations

Is there a $1$-dimensional foliation of $S^3$ which is not a geodesible foliation? Is there a $1$-dimensional foliation of $S^2\times S^1$ which is not a geodesible foliation?

If the answer is affirmative, can one produce an example of a non-geodesible foliation of $S^3$ or $S^2\times S^1$ whose leaves are mapped to the singular foliation of $S^2$ associated to the Poincaré compactification of a planar quadratic vector field? (By "mapped" we mean the Hopf map $S^3\to S^2$ or the projection $S^2\times S^1\to S^2$.)

For detailed motivation please see the [following post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333425/hilbert-16th-problem-and-dynamical-lefschetz-trace-formula?rq=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a 1-dimensional foliation of a 3-manifold contains a Reeb component, then it is not geodesible. This follows from a theorem of [Sullivan](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(78)90046-4), see [Section 2.5, Obstruction 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5084). A *Reeb component* is a saturated annulus embedded in the manifold with induced foliation looking like:

[image]

One can find a 1-dimensional foliation of any 3-manifold containing such a Reeb component. Foliate $T^2\times I = S^1 \times (S^1\times I)$ by foliating $S^1\times I$ by the Reeb foliation, and extending by the product with $S^1$ to $T^2 \times I$. Now, embed $T^2\times I$ in a manifold $M$ with this foliation, and extend it to a 1-dimensional foliation on the rest of $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful  answer.